# Swift rounded buttons with constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

In an iOS 9 iPhone app I have a button which I want to have rounded corners, so it's completely rounded. I added a button to my Storyboard and gave added two constraints to center it horizontally and vertically. This was all working until I addded a few lines of code to apply rounded corners to the button. This is my storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYL4d.png Then I added the following lines of code to my view controller:

```
startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 75
startButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
startButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

When I run this is an iPhone 5s simulator, the border is messed up, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtVJX.png
I've been trying make the button completely rounded for days, but with no result. What can I do?

Comment: You can experiment with something like this: `yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 75, 75)
        yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.bounds.size.width / 2.0
        yourButton.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: I removed the cornerRadius and set masksToBounds to true and now I have a square border around the button. Now I get why I'm getting the effect like on the second screenshot. The button is 150x150 in size, but the border is displayed around the text, not around the 150x150. What can I do to make the border appear around the 150x150?

Comment: Closed per the request of the asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating it entirely programatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 50, 50) // (x, y, width, height)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    button.setTitle("Hi!", forState: .Normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("hello!")
}
```

Obviously a lot of these customisations are optional (e.g. background color) but just to show you that you can still do everything you want to with the button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `cornerRadius` is bigger than its height. Try the following code in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.bounds.size.height / 2
    startButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
    startButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all make the button completely square, then round the corner by half of its width or height.

E.g:

```js
// 200*200 square button
startButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

// make the corner rounded like circle
startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.size.height/2

startButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
startButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```